# New commerce site checkout broken

Tags: commerce

It turned out there were two issues here: first checkout stopped working, then the server ran out of space. I now have space on the server, but the checkout still isn't working.

It's a commerce site, and checkout worked fine until launch and now the process appears to be broken. I get this message in the Drupal error log.

> Notice: Undefined index: field_extra_instructions in commerce_customer_profile_pane_checkout_form() (line 165 of /home/wholebox.org/www/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/customer/includes/commerce_customer.checkout_pane.inc).

The site is wholebox.org and if anyone can help find out what's wrong, it would be very handy right now.

Could I have disabled an important module when trying to make it faster?

Comment: It could be a 403 page- but now my 403 report page is displaying an error - file could not be created

Comment: I don't see any error. Do you have any error message or behaviour. Take a look in the log messages in admin/reports/dblog.

Comment: take a look in your temp folder permissions setting.. and make sure that the path is correct. More info http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory

Comment: added a php error...

Comment: when I put something on the production server i disable the devel module. Check also the tmp folder too and the space in your server. But it is probably a permission issue with your tmp.

Comment: should the tmp folder be at the root directory of the website? I don't know where to find it

Comment: yeah it was disabled but i thought i'd re-enable to try and debug the problem

Comment: are you using Linux or windows in your production server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7189/discussion-between-cayerdis-and-alex-lee)

Comment: linux - i don't have shell access though, just SFTP

Comment: In my settings /config/media/file-system in temporary directory. I use /tmp withoud slash. More info this article helped me http://sandu.camerzan.md/content/fix-file-upload-error-could-not-move-uploaded-file-drupal-7-how

Comment: Disk space issue resolved -server admin sorted it. But checkout still broken... I get this... Notice: Undefined index: field_extra_instructions in commerce_customer_profile_pane_checkout_form() (line 165 of /home/wholebox.org/www/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/customer/includes/commerce_customer.checkout_pane.inc).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout problem - there are two possibilities that fixed it, as I re-enabled Extra Panes and Coupon UI at the same time.

I had set an extra field in Customer Shipping Profile. I didn't think it was dependent on Commerce Extra Panes, but when I disabled that module the process broke.

It could also be that the coupon UI module provides the text box on the checkout process, so when I disabled that it broke it.

Thanks for everyone's help in the comments above :)