# Unable to install themes on new Drupal install

Tags: theming, installation

Note: I'm self hosting Drupal so I have full access to the server -- searching for this error seems to only bring up solutions to shared hosting situations.

I'm running a Drupal multi-site installation and attempting to install a new theme via the GUI. After logging in as admin, I go to Appearance -> Install New Theme -> and upload my tar.gz file. I get the following error:

```
Unable to create directory 'temporary:'
```

I've navigated to the File System settings in Drupal and changed around the location of the temp folder, created a new folder, used the entire path to the folder, set 777 permissions on everything, made www-data the owner of every folder imaginable, and nothing is working. I'm absolutely positive the folder I'm specifying as the temp folder exists, because the theme I'm trying to upload is uploaded to said folder.

Yep, I'm actually uploading a file, but Drupal tells me it can't create a directory.

Has anyone encountered this type of error? I'm using Drupal 7.28 on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Did you tried to upload a zip archive of your theme instead of tar.gz?

Comment: I have, with no luck. Now I get this: Warning: filesize(): stat failed for temporary://zippys.tar.gz in file_save() (line 601 of /var/www/html/Platform/includes/file.inc).

Comment: Well try to search for changing `file upload size` in php.ini

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the base folders permissions and not only the contents of the temporary folder? What command are you using to set the permissions of the temporary directory?  Also, are you using Apache or something else?  My default temporary directory was actually /tmp in Ubuntu 14.04 w/ Apache. Also, are you using SELinux? See: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97216/module-installation-unable-to-create-directory-temporary-update-extraction-f . The paths could be off as well: https://www.drupal.org/node/1019096#comment-4288882