# How to reinstall Drupal?

Tags: 7, installation

Can anyone tell me the best possible way of how to reinstall Drupal 7 from ubuntu 13.04? After googling came through many options that is making me confused!

Comment: you can try resetting "settings.php" and do the install again by providing the new database name and password.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the following steps too :

1. Go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`
2. Select your database and drop all the tables
3. Go to `http://yoursite.com/install.php`

Or you can use : `drush si`

And done.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal Community Documentation - Installation Guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/install)

or if you want to install it from the Ubuntu packaging system, you can execute this to remove Drupal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove
```

Then execute this to install it again.

```
sudo apt-get install drupal
```

Comment: Thank you for your warm response. Actually we installed Drupal 7 once and was working on it. But recently its showing file permission errors,due to which we need to uninstall Drupal 7 completely from Ubuntu 13.04 and re-install again. Can you specifically state me the steps?

Comment: I think your main problem is configuring your server properly to fix the file permission errors, instead of re-installing Drupal. Re-installing won't fix those file permission errors. In any case, I modified my answer to include the command to uninstall Drupal.

Comment: Ok ,when we tried to add images in our website ,its showing an error message as " The specified file temporary://kniji_0.jpg could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log"........can you suggest me with the  possible solution for removing this error?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/30118/1134