# Directory permissions and appearance issues after moving site

Tags: files, debugging

I recently moved my drupal site and am having issues with it the most pressing issue is one of permissions for temporary directory. there is also some weird css stuff going on but ill figure them ut when the errors have been fixed. the error i am getting is:
`The specified file temporary://filewjfbY3 could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.`

Here is where the temp directory is set:

[image: temp directory]

Here is the permissions of `tmp` in file zilla. the tmp folder is in the root directory.

[image]

i have tried creating new temp dir and changing it in the configuration with no success.

Comment: Your have created "temp" dir not "tmp". In file setting you need to chang dir name. Need to set write permission too.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand where you are getting the temp from @VimalGoradiya.

Comment: have you tried with 777 permission?

Comment: Yes i have but still dosnt work

Comment: I think "destination directory" means the files final destination i.e. sites/yoursite/files. Make sure your webserver can write there.

Comment: @KariKääriäinen can you elaborate.

Comment: Please check for example: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/30113/7641