# "The specified file temporary://fileXXXXXX could not be copied" warning

Tags: files

If i open my local website there is a indication like this.

> The specified file temporary://filel17IDM could not be copied, because
>   the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be
>   caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More
>   information is available in the system log.

how to get out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary directory set under **Admin > Configuration > File System** is incorrect or does not have write permissions. Typically for local dev (on Linux/OSX machines) this path can simply be `/tmp`. On Windows, I believe it is `C:\temp`.

See: [Configuring the temporary directory](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory)

Comment: The file was already copied to the temporary directory. The possible permission problems would be in the destination directory.

Answer (score 7):

> The specified file temporary://filel17IDM could not be copied, because the **destination directory** is not properly configured.

The problem is with the destination directory, not the temporary directory (which defaults to `/tmp` on Linux systems).

`/tmp` typically looks like this:

```
ls -la /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 4096 Feb 19 09:52 .
```

Which means that any user can write to the directory.

Check the permissions of your `files/` directory, and any directories it contains. They should be writable by the webserver.

Also check that the destination **folder** exists and has the correct permissions, for example `files/translations/` may not exist and you'll get the error message mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I didn't have a folder called `translations` in the `files` folder typically stored in `sites/[site_path]/files`.

Creating a `translations` folder at `sites/default/files/translations` fixed it for me.

Comment: This folder also gets created automatically when you go to /admin/config/media/file-system and save the form once.