# Clean URLs caused site to break?

Tags: 8

I'm installing a new Drupal site using Red Hat... Getting Clean URLs to work was a pain in the you-know-what. I followed all the steps in the official drupal.org helpguide, but ended up needing extra help for a guide specific to RHEL users here: https://www.tecmint.com/install-drupal-in-centos-rhel-fedora/

I went into my httpd.conf file and made AllowOveride All as shown here: https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Enable-Clean-URL-in-Drupal.png

I then fixed all of my directory issues in .htaccess (because my .htaccess file is in sites/web), and then all my admin links work perfectly. So Clean URLs is definitely enabled, but the issue now is the site is broken.

[image: Drupal 8 broken site]

This was probably caused by enabling Clean URLs through the httpd.conf issue, but I'm not sure. I ran drush cr and it did nothing. Help?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) The site isn't broken. It's just the stylesheets are missing. Maybe uncomment `RewriteBase /` in your site's .htaccess. Maybe make make your files and temp dirs writeable recursively. But definitely check your site's status page for more info.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions... It turned out, actually, that I had to uncheck aggregate css. Duh!

Comment: That sounds more like a misconfigured tmp/files directory to me.

Answer (score 1):

As leymannx and Kevin mention it is probably a misconfigured tmp/files directory

**Uncheck aggregate css** is something that you would not want on your live site as the performance will suffer.

Check in *Reports > status report* (/admin/reports/status) and try to fix or report on the errors that you see.

Also go into *configuration > media > file system* (/admin/config/media/file-system) and correct any file system problems reported when saving the settings.

The most probable cause of what you are seeing is wrong permissions.

There is a lot of guides on the net about setting those permissions. 
You can start from the [official guide on the subject](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) or on [one support thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory) that started as a drupal 7 thread but has Drupal 8 answers.